# Typescript definition file with submodules

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using the [Vortex Web](http://www.prismtech.com/vortex/vortex-web) JavaScript library within my TypeScript source code which provides the `dds` object. Here's a snippet:

```
var runtime = new dds.runtime.Runtime();
runtime.connect("ws://localhost:9000", "user:pass");

var chatTopic = new dds.Topic(0, 'ChatMessage');
runtime.registerTopic(chatTopic);
```

For this library I want to write a definition file.

Here's my current attempt:

```
declare module VortexWebClient {

    interface TopicQos {
        new (): TopicQos;
    }

    interface Topic {
        new (domainID: number, topicName: string): Topic;
        new (domainID: number, topicName: string, tqos: TopicQos): Topic;
        new (domainID: number, topicName: string, tqos: TopicQos, topicType: string): Topic;
        new (domainID: number, topicName: string, tqos: TopicQos, topicType: string, typeName: string): Topic;
    }   

    interface Runtime {
        new (): Runtime;
        connect(server: string, authToken: string);
        disconnect();
        registerTopic(topic: Topic);
    }

    interface runtime {
        Runtime: Runtime;
    }


    export interface DDS {
        runtime : runtime;
        Topic : Topic;
        VERSION: string;
    }


}

declare var dds: VortexWebClient.DDS;
```

This works but it looks to me that there should be a better way using the `export` keyword. Especially listing all the members for the `DDS` interface at the bottom  (there are still a lot more to write) should be avoided.

I tried many different ways, one of them was the following. It should avoid explicitly creating the dds interface which is just a wrapper so to say:

```
declare module DDS {

    export interface TopicQos {
        new (): TopicQos;
    }

    export interface Topic {
        new (domainID: number, topicName: string): Topic;
        new (domainID: number, topicName: string, tqos: TopicQos): Topic;
        new (domainID: number, topicName: string, tqos: TopicQos, topicType: string): Topic;
        new (domainID: number, topicName: string, tqos: TopicQos, topicType: string, typeName: string): Topic;
    }

    interface Runtime {
        new (): Runtime;
        connect(server: string, authToken: string);
        disconnect();
        registerTopic(topic: Topic);
    }

    export interface runtime {
        Runtime: Runtime;
    }

    export var VERSION: string;

}

//Here IntelliJ complaints: "Cannot find name: DDS"
declare var dds: DDS;
```

**What's the correct way of creating a definition file which includes several submodules?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in this line:

```
declare var dds: DDS;
```

Is because `DDS` is not a type, it's a module. But you're trying to use it as a type.

You could instead just rename `DDS` to `dds`, and it would then effectively be a variable holding an object with the internal structure you've declared.

Comment: How are they not found? `var x: dds.Runtime` should work fine. If you want them to be accessible without the `dds` prefix, move them out of the `dds` module.

Comment: @SailAvid - I was able to get your bottom definition compiling by changing `declare var dds: DDS;` to `declare var dds: typeof DDS;`.  To get it working with the code sample, I had to additionally change `export interface runtime {` to `export var runtime : {` which says "there is something called runtime that is an object with the properties in the curly braces".

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the beginning of your example, `dds` is a global object.

```
declare var dds: any;
```

It has a `runtime` property.

```
declare var dds: { runtime : any};
```

`runtime` has a property called `Runtime` that is a class with a constructor that takes no arguments.

```
declare var dds: {
  runtime : {
    Runtime: typeof Runtime
  }
};

declare class Runtime {
  constructor();
}
```

The `Runtime` class has a method called `connect` that takes two strings and returns void.

```
declare var dds: {
  runtime : {
    Runtime: typeof Runtime
  }
};

declare class Runtime {
  constructor();
  connect(server: string, authToken: string): void;
}
```

This fills your initial requirement.  Now let's tidy things up by putting all of the types (except `dds` which is global) in a `VortexWeb` module.

```
declare module VortexWeb {
  export class Runtime {
    constructor();
    connect(server: string, authToken: string): void;
  }
}

declare var dds: {
  runtime : {
    Runtime: typeof VortexWeb.Runtime
  }
};
```

That's your starter definition.  Hope that helps!